# Create a symbolic link on shared folder between guest Ubuntu and host Windows on VM Virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

First of all let me apologize because I know there are many topics related to my issue. But I was not able to solve it so have to ask community. Not sure is it a Linux specific topic or VM Virtual box issue but here is my problem description:

1. I have a VM Virtual box with Ubuntu as a guest OS and Windows as a
   host.
2. I shared folder between them. I also switched on option to be
   able [create symbolic links inside shared folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/345341/cant-create-symlinks-in-virtualbox-shared-folders)
3. Network is set up with NAT with Port Forwarding.
4. I have a PhpStorm installed on host operation system (in my case Windows) and all source file stored on guest operation system (Ubuntu).
5. So I want one folder have full access for guest and host so I can edit source code with PhpStorm and use the same source on Ubuntu. So from inside Ubuntu **I have tried make symbolic link on shared folder**. And here I have troubles (see an attachment). [image: log]

On the left site here is my workspace folder with projects. And on the right I have tried to create a link inside shared (sf_) folder.

P.S. I do not wana use SSH deploy on phpStorm :(

Comment: This won't work, because the link is not a symbolic link in a linux filesystem but a link in the underlying NTFS filesystem. In Virtualbox you can only create a link on a shared folder if source and destination is on the same share.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So I used another approach that I did not want: I use "Deployment" feature from PhpStorm.

Comment: There are symlink-s on Windows now.  But the VirtualBox has a bug that probably means it can't work any way - See:  [ticket #10085](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085).